# How to SIMPLY serve index.html with django?

Tags: python, html, django

sof,

I just installed django 1.9 on my ubuntu box.

I want to deploy a lightweight django app.

I did this:

```
cd ~
django-admin startproject dj10
cd ~/dj10/dj10/
mkdir templates
echo hello > templates/index.html
```

How to configure
`~/dj10/dj10/`
so that django will serve `~/dj10/dj10/templates/index.html`
when I GET `/index.html`
??

I tried editing `~/dj10/dj10/urls.py` so it looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Then I added this file:

```
~/dj10/dj10/views.py
```

which looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Next I started the server:

```
cd ~/dj10/
python manage.py runserver
```

Here is what I want to happen.

- Browswer GETs `/index.html`
- `~/dj10/dj10/urls.py` matches `/index.html` to `views.index`
- python runs `index()` inside of `views.py`
- `index()` finds `index.html` here: `~/dj10/dj10/templates/index.html`
- `index()` renders `index.html`

Instead I see this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://lh:8000/index.html

Using the URLconf defined in dj10.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^admin/
    ^$ [name='index']
The current URL, index.html, didn't match any of these.
```

So, I probably have a syntax error in either `urls.py` or `views.py`?
Maybe I should add some syntax to ... 
`~/dj10/dj10/settings.py`
??

Here is the question again:

How to configure
`~/dj10/dj10/`
so that django will serve `~/dj10/dj10/templates/index.html`
when I GET `/index.html`
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to SIMPLY serve index.html with Django:

```
git clone https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started dj101
cd dj101
vi hello/templates/index.html
pip install -r requirements.txt
git commit -am hello
heroku local
heroku create dj101
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to specifically serve the url "index.html". You have configured Django to serve that HTML file in response to the path "/", which is the correct thing to do. There is no reason to use the template name in the path, and it is much better practice not to do so.

If you really did want to do this for some reason, you would need to specify that exact file path in your urls.py:

```
 url(r'^index.html$', views.index, name='index'),
```

but as I say, you should not do this.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I tried this:

    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib import admin
    
    from . import views
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^index.html$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]

I saw this response in my browser:

    TemplateDoesNotExist at /index.html
    
    index.html
    
    Request Method:  GET
    Request URL:  http://lh:8000/index.html
    Django Version:  1.9
    Exception Type:  TemplateDoesNotExist
    Exception Value:

Comment: Well, my suggestion was *not* to do that, but never mind. You should show the TEMPLATES section of your settings; also it looks like your templates directory is one level too deep, it should be in the base dj10 directory.

Comment: Also note, if all you want to do is display the static text "hello", there's no reason for a template at all; just do `return HttpResponse('hello')` in your view.

Comment: I agree that ~/dj10/dj10/templates/ looks too deep.
But when I ran 
django-admin startproject dj10
django gave me this:
~/dj10/dj10/
Based on what I read in the tutorial,
I should put my code in ~/dj10/dj10/.

Comment: Yes, that's where the project settings and urls live. But you shouldn't create new files or directories in there - everything else should be one level higher, ie as siblings to that directory not children of it.

Comment: The purpose of my post is to find a way to SIMPLY serve index.html , I dont want to know how to serve a string. 

Also I already know how to serve index.html from a clone of the polls tutorial.

That tutorial suggests I need to run this shell command:

python manage.py startapp polls

If I want to serve just 1 page do I need to run startapp?

It appears that django-admin startproject lays down a lot of code.

Is that code enough to serve a simple index.html if I configure these files:

settings.py
urls.py
views.py
??

Comment: I don't know why you've said all that, I told you what the problem is. Nevertheless Django is really meant for generating complex data driven sites; it is not for serving static content. If you want that you should just configure a standard web server line Apache or nginx.